# Use of path-dependent type as a class parameter

Tags: scala

I want to have a class which takes a parameter with a class-dependent type, as I've often done for methods. However, to my surprise, this didn't work:

```
scala> trait Compiler { trait Config }
defined trait Compiler

// works fine, as expected
scala> def f(c: Compiler)(conf: c.Config) = {}
f: (c: Compiler)(conf: c.Config)Unit

scala> class F(val c: Compiler)(val conf: c.Config)
<console>:8: error: not found: value c
       class F(val c: Compiler)(val conf: c.Config)
                                          ^
```

Why? And are there any workarounds?

Comment: I got the following **without currying**: `<console>:11: error: illegal dependent method type: parameter appears in the type of another parameter in the same section or an earlier one
       class F(val c: Compiler, val conf: c.Config)
                   ^`

Comment: @KevinMeredith The error without currying is expected (it's the same for methods) and seems clear enough to me, even if I would prefer it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround which seems acceptable (can't create an invalid `F` without additional casts):

```
class F private (val c: Compiler)(_conf: Compiler#Config) {
  def conf = _conf.asInstanceOf[c.Config]
}

object F {
  def apply(c: Compiler)(conf: c.Config) = new F(c)(conf)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As to why path-dependent types do not work in a class primary constructor
 the answer is given in section 5.3 of the Scala language specification:

> a formal value parameter may not form part of the types of any of the
>   parent classes or members of the class template

(though it seems that "members of the class template" means only the members defined within the constructor parameter sections).

But a class may have additional constructors that make it possible to write a workaround that does not need additional casts and objects:

```
class F private (val conf: Compiler#Config, val c: Compiler) {
    def this(c: Compiler)(conf: c.Config) = this(conf, c)
}
```